# Finale writing problem, four cross-beamed eighths

Tags: software, engraving, beaming, finale

How do I enter cross-beamed eighth notes in Finale?

[image: multi-voice notation with cross-beamed eighth notes]

Comment: This question is lacking some detail. Please elaborate on what is causing you problems. Is it the cross staff beaming in the alto? Then just try this: https://www.finalemusic.com/blog/finale-quicktips-cross-staff-beaming/ . Is it having multiple voices? Then maybe https://usermanuals.finalemusic.com/FinaleMac/Content/Finale/Multiple_voices.htm can help you.

Comment: @Lazy The first one!!! Thank you. Sorry for the lacking of detail, I am asking for my friend, still - great answer.

Answer (score 1):

In case the link https://www.finalemusic.com/blog/finale-quicktips-cross-staff-beaming/ dies:

**Finale QuickTips: Cross-Staff Beaming**

1. Write all of your notes for the cross-staff passage in one staff.
2. Choose the Selection tool then click and drag to select the notes you wish to move.
3. After you have selected the region of notes you wish to move, press ALT+SHIFT+Up/Down Arrow (Win) or OPTION+SHIFT+Up/Down Arrow (Mac). (*no shift in Finale 2014 or later for Mac)
4. You can then use the Beam Angle tool from the Special Tools palette (Window > Special Tools Palette) to alter the beam height and angle.